# Expressing any given number in terms of million

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a jquery function to express  any given number in terms of million.
For eg

```
1,000,000 = 1,

450,0000 = 0.45,

25,000 = 0.025,

500,780,000 = 500.78
```

Without converting them to string is it possible to achieve this using jquery or javascript.
Thank you

Update: The comma is only for readability so these will be ignored during actual calculation.

Comment: have you tried something ?

Comment: Have you considered some arithmetic, a division, maybe?

Comment: `1,000,000` is not a number. It is a string with commas.

Comment: consider usinmg something like this: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/numberformatter

Comment: yes, 1,000,000 is not a number and you should first try yourself.

Comment: This is, on the face of it, such an incredibly easy task that I have to wonder if I'm reading it wrong. Is there some kind of wrinkle somewhere that'll keep x/1000000 from working?

Comment: This is JavaScript, jQuery is a tool for DOM-manipulation. Even if there may be jQuery plugins doing things like this, please don't use them. Vanilla JS does not bite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. 
Just divide the number by 1000000 and use parseInt. Also you can keep the commas if you use parseInt

```
parseInt('1,000,000'.replace(/,/g, ''))/1000000 = 1
parseInt('450,000'.replace(/,/g, ''))/1000000 = 0.45
And so on...
```

Also if the numbers will be floats you can do

```
parseFloat('1,000,000'.replace(/,/g, ''))/1000000 = 1
parseFloat('450,000'.replace(/,/g, ''))/1000000 = 0.45
```

**Update:** Here is the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/E4UCL/1/

Comment: No no no no no... `parseInt` won't help.

Comment: It won't, see here http://jsfiddle.net/E4UCL/. The first one equates to 0.000001 **not** 1. The second equates to 0.00045.

Comment: Like @VisioN said, this will not work. `parseInt(1,000,000)` evaluates to 1. Do people even read the answer before upvoting?

Comment: @ryanbrill Without the commas, `parseInt(1000000)` evaluates to 1. With the commas, `parseInt(1,000,000)` evaulates to 0.000001

Comment: Hi All. Sorry for the confusion with the commas. I just wanted to put i t there for readability purpose. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @mattytommo Nope. Run the code. You're running it with the division included.